# Generate random number with different probabilities for each line in R

Tags: r, random

I want to generate a random number u from 1 to 4 for each line in my data.frame. However, the probabilities are different for each line and these probabilities are stored in the variables p00, p10, p01, p11. This means that the probability for 1 is p00, for 2 p01 etc.. I have 406611 lines in my data.frame. data01 contains the variables p00, p10, p01, p11.

I am doing the following

```
data02 <- data01 %>%
mutate (u = sample(x=c(1:4), size=406611, replace = T, prob=c(p00, p10, p01, p11))
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
incorrect number of probabilities.
```

If I do this (just to try) I do not get any error:

```
data02 <- data01 %>%
mutate (u = sample(x=c(1:4), size=406611, replace = T, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
```

Why is this not working? How can I generate the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing 4 vectors to the `probs` parameter of `sample` (the entire columns p00, p10, p01, and p11), but `sample` is not vectorised in this way, and only takes a *single* vector of probabilities.

You need to write a version of `sample` that is vectorized on `probs`. Something like this:

```
vec_sample <- function(A, B, C, D)
{
  do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(A), function(i)
  {
    sample(1:4, 1, replace = TRUE, prob=c(A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]))
  }))
}
```

So your code would work like this:

```
data02 <- data01 %>% mutate(u = vec_sample(p00, p10, p01, p11))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Allan!! You were right. However, I needed to include "size = 1" in the sample function otherwise it generated 4 values but I only needed one. Thank you so much again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another convenient option is `pmap` to loop over the rows and use the values in 'p00' to 'p11' columns used as a vector in the `prob`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data01 %>%
       mutate(u = pmap_int(select(., p00, p10, p01, p11),
                  ~sample(1:4, 1, prob = c(...))))
```